# Is it possible to detect whether a jQuery click event has been called by actual click or trigger?

Tags: jquery, button, triggers, click

I have some functionality which is bound to a click event:

```
$('.addButton').live('click', function(){  
 //stuff here...
});
```

Sometimes the function is called by an actual button click, and sometimes using `trigger()`. Is there a way to detect which method has been used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

```
$('.addButton').live('click', function(e){ 
    if(e.which != undefined){
         //actual button click
    }
    else{
         //trigger
    }
});
```

See example here: [http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/d5SW2/](http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/d5SW2/1/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can pass another argument to .live that contains eventData

```
.live( eventType, eventData, handler )
// eventData A map of data that will be passed to the event handler.
```

Would it be possible to use this to contain an indicator as to how the callee made the call?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes.

```
$('.addButton').live('click', function(event){  
if(event.clientX === undefined)
  console.log("Invoked programatically")
});
```

Of course you can emulate that, if you want. But it's not there by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra parameters to the trigger function and use the to distinguish the possible sources...